# How to signInWithRedirect() without redirecting it to the Installed WebApp?

Tags: google-chrome, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps

I am using firebase-auth `signInWithRedirect()`. Everything works fine except in a case where user has the corresponding WebApp installed (i.e. Add to Homescreen), but signing-in via Chrome Browser (instead of WebApp).

It seems that when I called `signInWithRedirect()` in Chrome Browser, Chrome will somehow launch the corresponding installed WebApp after a successful login, then the WebApp will close and redirect back to google sign-in page and get stuck there with the loading screen.

My guessing is that the Chrome PWA, and the installed WebApp are different instances, as such the auth token got confused. Is there any workaround to force `signInWithRedirect()` to only redirect to Chrome when user initiate the sign-in from Chrome? How does Chrome know when to redirect to a Chrome PWA, or a installed WebApp?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it is related to this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771418
The fix should be out in 64.0.3254.2

Comment: Just tested with Chrome v65, but the problem still not resolved.